# How to delete files that are older then 7 years in a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have a site that has files created before 7 years(before 2015). I need to delete all of them by applying filters (Filename has the file created date on it Example:20130204.PDF). Could anyone please provide the powershell script for deleting these files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of sites, libraries and files you have it might not be the best approach to use powershell.

Unless this is a one-off house cleaning, it might be best to enable the retention policy of your SharePoint libraries to delete content older (create before) 7 years.